# SQL order multiple data rows without combining the rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

For a notification system, I am trying to take multiple rows of completely seperate data, and order them using a unix time stamp.  The data from each row is selected by using a users USERID, and then the rows should be ordered from the time they occured.

for example, one of the tables being selected would be:

```
- USERID   msgid    timestamp
-   3        5       1234567
```

A final table after selecting all relevant data should look like:

```
- USERID    msgid    postid    playerpostid     friendrequestid     timestamp  
-   3         5                                                      1234567
-   3                  5                                             1234566
-   3        1234                                                    1234565
-   3                               542                              1234564
```

As you can see, the tables all combine, but the only thing connecting them is the USERID, and ordered by the timestamp.

Ive tried joins, unfortunately that multiples the results to a ridiculous amount of results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    USERID, msgid, NULL AS postid, NULL AS playerpostid, NULL AS friendrequestid, timestamp
  FROM messages
  WHERE USERID=3

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    USERID, NULL AS msgid, postid, NULL AS playerpostid, NULL AS friendrequestid, timestamp
  FROM posts
  WHERE USERID=3

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    USERID, NULL AS msgid, NULL AS postid, playerpostid, NULL AS friendrequestid, timestamp
  FROM playerposts
  WHERE USERID=3

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    USERID, NULL AS msgid, NULL AS postid, NULL playerpostid, friendrequestid, timestamp
  FROM friendrequests
  WHERE USERID=3
) AS baseview
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: And you can safely use `UNION ALL` for better performance. Just in case you remove the `WHERE` conditions and you have many rows. The default is `UNION DISTINCT` which can be very slow with big tables.